# Renaming same labels in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I do not have my code available to me right now, and I cannot post it; however, I do a .drop_duplicates method for a dataframe and have multiple rows with the same label.  How do I rename the labels such that the name "Terry" would change to "Terry 1", "Terry 2", "Terry 3" and so forth?

Here is some mock up code:

```
series1 = ['M','M','S','S','S','T','T']
series2 = [1,2,1,1,3,4,4]
series3 = [2,4,2,2,2,2,2]
data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Name':series1,'Number 1': series2,'Number 2':series3})
```

I am trying to change the names to M_0,M_1,S_0,S_1,S_0, etc... based on if it matches a previous label

Comment: "I do not have my code available to me right now, and I cannot post it" then please don't post your question until you do.

Comment: I apologize, but I am not actually able to post my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this would help.
My sample df:

```
       col2
col1       
Jack      1
Terry     2
Paul      3
Terry     4
Terry     5
```

I will then place the index in a list and use Jochen Ritzel's function in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837409/how-to-append-count-numbers-to-duplicates-in-a-list-in-python) solution to deal with the duplicates (I modified his function to add a number after the duplicate index).

The function is here:

```
def rename_duplicates(old): 
        seen = {} 
        for x in old: 
            if x in seen: 
                seen[x] += 1 
                yield "%s%d" % (x, seen[x]) 
            else: 
                seen[x] = 0 
                yield x
```

Then store the new index:

```
new_index = list(rename_duplicates(indexList))
```

now all you have to do is to change the index in your current df to the new one as follows:

```
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df.index = new_index
```